# Oauth login session require session support error in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, session, oauth

I'm getting this error from express session although I've used it before initializing passport.

```
Error: Login sessions require session support. Did you forget to use `express-session` middleware?
    at SessionManager.logIn (G:\react\sunglasses-api\node_modules\passport\lib\sessionmanager.js:21:33)
    at req.login.req.logIn (G:\react\sunglasses-api\node_modules\passport\lib\http\request.js:39:26)
    at strategy.success (G:\react\sunglasses-api\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:256:13)
    at verified (G:\react\sunglasses-api\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\strategy.js:189:20)
    at Strategy._verify (G:\react\sunglasses-api\middleware\passport.js:18:14)
    at G:\react\sunglasses-api\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\strategy.js:198:24
    at G:\react\sunglasses-api\node_modules\passport-google-oauth2\lib\oauth2.js:165:7
    at passBackControl (G:\react\sunglasses-api\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:134:9)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (G:\react\sunglasses-api\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:157:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:525:35)
```

Below is my code related to express and passport initialization

```
//session initialization
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "ludwigdieter",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { secure: true }
  })
);

//passport initialization
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```